# Spring data REST & data security

Tags: spring-data-rest

So I have a nice set of Spring Data REST repositories and they work great.  Now I want to secure the data they produce.  The URLs to the repositories are secure, in that, only an authenticated user has authorization to call them.  However, only data in the database associated to the user should be sent to the client.

I have implemented an interceptor which gets called prior to the repository call which contains information about the logged in user, but I'm not sure how I can ensure only data produced by the REST call is data associated to the logged in user.

Obviously the client is coded to only make calls with links associated to the currently logged in user, but a user could simply change the URL to look at data they are not supposed to see.

Has anyone solved this issue?

Thanks,

Cory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using spring security, you can insert additional filters (ideally, based upon the url, or domain object.)

If you want object level security, you can still do the same thing, but you're going to have to somehow specify who/what role is allowed to access which domain object/id combinations, in either case, I don't think spring data rest handles (or should handle) any of that.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a gist of how you'd implement this then, seeing as Spring can't do it out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security's @PostFilter allows you to filter collection or arrays on the basis of authorization.

```
@PostFilter ("filterObject.owner == authentication.name")
public List<Book> getBooks();
```

Check these documented examples
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security